# Five full-screen buttons in embedded Youtube videos

Tags: applications, chrome-for-android, video, media-player

I am using Android Chrome. Why I am seeing four additional full-screen buttons in the embedded Youtube players as shown below, instead of the play and other buttons. The issue reproduces on various websites.

[image: Five full-screen buttons in embedded Youtube player]

The problem reproduces even if I check the "show in desktop mode". The videos start to play when I click the left-most button where the play button should be. Sometimes the four gear icons start to flicker replacing the full-screen buttons.

These issues appeared recently, maybe a couple of weeks ago. I use Chrome version 113.0.5672.77; the Android is the latest native 12. The phone is CAT S42.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Could you also [edit] and mention the device model, and whether you're using a custom ROM/rooted and further customizations/modifications?

Comment: Nobody hasn't reproduced the issue? Could this relate to the New Pipe also installed on my phone? Is there some general-purpose Youtube player on Androids used by the Chrome browser and messed by the New Pipe?

Comment: Android apps generally cannot access other apps' data. However, if this happens on Chrome, perhaps the issue was from the resources delivered by YouTube itself? Have you tried clearing the cache of Chrome (3-vertical dots - Settings - Privacy and security - Clear browsing data - Cached images and files - Clear data)?

Comment: Thanks @AndrewT. I used the Chrome and went to youtube.com, opened the three-dot menu and info icon. I cleared the cookies and other site info there specifically for Youtube without luck. I also tried using incognito tab, the issue persists.